# Unable to keep NA values in my output when calculating mean

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
EBOV (group_11) OmicronSpike (group_11) OmicronRBD (group_11) ID Well Tube_patient dpfd lab_id label
2103.0 547652.0 2693.0 PBS H1 PBS 0 PBS well_1
0.0 0.0 0.0 PBS H1 PBS 0 PBS well_1
1924.5 599256.0 2601.0 PBS H2 PBS 0 PBS well_1
1793.0 567137.0 2535.0 PBS H2 PBS 0 PBS well_1
1936.0 NA 2484.0 PBS H3 PBS 0 PBS well_1
```

I aim to perform a mean calculation `group_by` in the column `label` and only in the columns that contain `"group_"` string in their column name.
With this in mind, I use the following line:

```
pbs_in_v1 <- pbs_in %>%
  group_by(label) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("group_"), 
                ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                .names = "{col}_mean"))
```

This code works only partially, because the calculated value replaces the `NAs` values with the mean result for that particular column. This is not correct because that `NA` value must be there, not be replaced by the mean result.

On the other hand, some values are `0.0`, but those values are from empty wells and should be treated like `NAs`. I tried to convert all values `0 or 0.0` to `NAs` in my data frame, using something like this:

```
pbs_in <- pbs_in %>%
group_by(label) %>%
   mutate(across(contains("group_"), 
                 ~ifelse(. == 0, NA, .)))
```

Even using this line, when I perform the `mean` calculation, all those `NAs` values are replaced by the mean, when the goal is to keep the `NAs`.
Here is my wrong output:

```
EBOV (group_11)_mean OmicronSpike (group_11)_mean OmicronRBD (group_11)_mean
1849.273 542322.1 2537.167
1849.273 542322.1 2537.167
1849.273 542322.1 2537.167
1849.273 542322.1 2537.167
1849.273 542322.1 2537.167
```

When the correct output must be:

```
1849.273 542322.1 2537.167
0.0 0.0 0.0
1849.273 542322.1 2537.167
1849.273 542322.1 2537.167
1849.273 NA 2537.167
```

So far, I could not find a way to perform an `ifelse` statement (maybe) to pass `NAs` and `0.0` values and not taking into account in my calculation, so the goal is to keep those cells (`NAs or 0.0`) without replacing the current value with the `mean result`.

I know that using `na.rm` must not take into account the `NAs` values, however, the output is showing me that most of the `NAs` are been replaced by the `mean result`.

Please the following figure, which only works to show the `NAs` (using `vis_miss`) where the right part of the plot is the new values calculated (black is `NAs`):
[image]

Questions:

What do I need to do to accomplish my goal?

What am I doing wrong?

Do I need to use an `ifelse` to avoid taking into account `NAs` and `0.0`?

If is that the case, what do I need to do to fix that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `0`s represent missing values, so I would first convert those to `NA`s. Then you can use `if_else()` inside `across()` to keep `NA` values as `NA`s in your mean columns.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pbs_in_v1 <- pbs_in %>%
  mutate(
    across(contains("group_"), ~na_if(., 0)),
    across(
      contains("group_"), 
      ~if_else(is.na(.), ., mean(., na.rm = TRUE)),
      .names = "{col}_mean"
    ),
    .by = label
  )
```

Result:

```
#> select(pbs_in_v1, ends_with("mean"))

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  `EBOV (group_11)_mean` `OmicronSpike (group_11)_mean` `OmicronRBD (group_11)_mean`
                   <dbl>                          <dbl>                        <dbl>
1                  1939.                        571348.                        2578.
2                    NA                             NA                           NA 
3                  1939.                        571348.                        2578.
4                  1939.                        571348.                        2578.
5                  1939.                            NA                         2578.
```